# Adobe Reader keep uninstalling when deployed via Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, adobe-reader

I've configured a Group Policy Object to install Adobe Reader X, but one machine keeps uninstalling the package on start-up - even if it is installed manually.

This one machine also doesn't show Reader as an installable app in Add/Remove programs.

Comment: GPO is doing you a favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the computer from the GPO.  Manually uninstall (remove registry entries and related files **BACKUP FIRST**) Adobe Reader X on the target machine after a gpupdate /force and a reboot.  Apply GPO to computer, gpupdate /force and reboot.  This has worked for me with a different MSI that I was having a similar problem.

Comment: ive attempted to do this before and once the GPO was reapplied its went back in to its loop

Answer (score 1):

I have been in this state when using an MSI before, I now tend to use BAT files to install example below is for installing VLC to networked computers

```
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" GOTO installer
Exit

:installer
\\NETWORKPATH\SHARE\vlc-1.1.7-win32.exe /s
EXIT
```

This checks if a file exists and if it does not then it will install the program.

This is simply a startup script used within a group policy :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled verbose Windows Installer logging, and checked the log files?  These are typically named msi*.log and located in a temporary folder, such as %systemroot%\temp.  The Windows Installer log files are usually very helpful in tracking down the issues.